# Capybara stuck when use chromedriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

Here is my code:

```
Capybara.register_driver :crm do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end
se = Capybara::Session.new(:crm)
se.visit("google.com")
```

It stucks for long time and raise this error:

> Uncaught exception: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
>
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64)

Here is my full env:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_wemedia $ bundle show selenium
/home/roroco/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.2
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_wemedia $ bundle show capybara
/home/roroco/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.11.0
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_wemedia $ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_wemedia $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18 Sarah
Release:    18
Codename:   sarah
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_wemedia $ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320)
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_wemedia $ google-chrome -version
Google Chrome 55.0.2883.87
```